# Any performance issue with Android 11 and 12 updates for particularly Samsung Galaxy Tab S7?

Tags: updates

I'm thinking of doing Android 11 (and 12 when available) update for my Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 (model: SM-T875) and seeking any advice that suggests avoiding the update.

Did you experience any performance issue in the new system such as battery drain, huge memory usage, instability, etc. so badly that you wish you wouldn't carry out the update?

Comment: I don't know if this can be considered as a performance issue, but [Samsung kills more apps since Android 11](https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung).

Comment: kindly keep this post open; I would like to hear more experiences.